# Video Streaming: Could not deserialize image after using pickle

Tags: python, numpy, opencv, pickle

I'm trying to create a video streaming application, which has 3 components:

1. An streaming application which streams via UDP the image received from camera
2. The UDP server which reads for data, puts it in a local file
3. HTTP Server, with a /cam.mjpg API, whose handler reads every 0.05 seconds from that pickle file, and transmits it (content type multipart)

I'm getting the following error:

```
----------------------------------------
Exception happened during processing of request from ('192.168.43.251', 54236)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/socketserver.py", line 613, in process_request_thread
    self.finish_request(request, client_address)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/socketserver.py", line 344, in finish_request
    self.RequestHandlerClass(request, client_address, self)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/socketserver.py", line 669, in __init__
    self.handle()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/http/server.py", line 398, in handle
    self.handle_one_request()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/http/server.py", line 386, in handle_one_request
    method()
  File "streaming_video_server2.py", line 25, in do_GET
    img = cv2.imdecode(img, x)
TypeError: only size-1 arrays can be converted to Python scalars
----------------------------------------
```

Here are my files, one by one (1, 2, 3)

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import cv2
from PIL import Image
import time
import datetime
import numpy as np
import socket
import sys
import _pickle as cPickle
import struct


def StartStreamSending():
    UDP_IP = "127.0.0.1"
    UDP_PORT = 8012
    capture=cv2.VideoCapture(0)
    capture.set(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH, 320);
    capture.set(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT, 240);
    clientsocket=socket.socket(socket.AF_INET,socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
    fourcc = cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc(*'MPEG')
    out = cv2.VideoWriter('output.avi',fourcc, 20.0, (320,240))


    while True:
        ret,img=capture.read()
        timestamp = datetime.datetime.now()
        ts = timestamp.strftime("%A %d %B %Y %I:%M:%S%p")
        cv2.putText(img, ts, (10, img.shape[0] - 10), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 0.35, (0, 0, 255), 1)
        #Store the frame into the output file
        out.write(img)
        #Some processing before sending the frame to webserver
        imgRGB=cv2.cvtColor(img,cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
        jpg = Image.fromarray(imgRGB)
        size = sys.getsizeof(imgRGB)
        print(size)

        result, img_str = cv2.imencode('.jpeg', img)
        #data = np.array(img_str)
        data = img_str

        dataToSend = cPickle.dumps(data)
        size = sys.getsizeof(dataToSend)
        print(size)
        print(type(dataToSend));

        clientsocket.sendto(dataToSend, (UDP_IP, UDP_PORT))

StartStreamSending()
```

File 2 : The UDP server which reads for data, puts it in a local file

```
import socket
import sys
import cv2
import _pickle as cPickle
import numpy as np
import struct

HOST='localhost'
PORT=8012

def WaitAndReceiveVideoStream(_strHOST, _iPORT):
    s=socket.socket(socket.AF_INET,socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
    print('Socket created')

    s.bind((_strHOST,_iPORT))
    print('Socket bind complete')



    data = ""
    #payload_size = struct.calcsize("L")

    i = 0
    while True:
        data, addr = s.recvfrom(66512)
        print(data)
        frame=cPickle.loads(data)
        i = i + 1
        print('coming frame' + str(i))

        with open('cam0.pickle', 'wb') as handle:
            cPickle.dump(frame, handle)

WaitAndReceiveVideoStream(HOST, PORT)
```

And the HTTP Server (File 3):

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import cv2
from PIL import Image
import numpy as np
import threading
from http.server import BaseHTTPRequestHandler,HTTPServer
import _pickle as cPickle
from socketserver import ThreadingMixIn
from io import StringIO,BytesIO
import time
import datetime

class CamHandler(BaseHTTPRequestHandler):
    def do_GET(self):
        if self.path.endswith('.mjpg'):
            self.send_response(200)
            self.send_header('Content-type','multipart/x-mixed-replace; boundary=--jpgboundary')
            self.end_headers()
            while True:
                try:
                    with open('cam0.pickle', 'rb') as handle:
                        img = cPickle.load(handle)
                        #use numpy to construct an array from the bytes
                        x = np.fromstring(img, dtype='uint8')
                        img = cv2.imdecode(img, x)
                    #Some processing before sending the frame to webserver
                    ##imgRGB=cv2.cvtColor(img,cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
                    ##jpg = Image.fromarray(imgRGB)
                    jpg = Image.fromarray(img)
                    tmpFile = BytesIO()
                    jpg.save(tmpFile,'JPEG')
                    self.wfile.write("--jpgboundary".encode())
                    self.send_header('Content-type','image/jpeg')
                    self.send_header('Content-length',str(tmpFile.getbuffer().nbytes))
                    print(str(tmpFile.getbuffer().nbytes))
                    self.end_headers()
                    jpg.save(self.wfile,'JPEG')
                    time.sleep(0.05)
                    print("Still inside mjpg")
                except KeyboardInterrupt:
                    break
                except ConnectionResetError:
                    break
            return
        if self.path.endswith('.html'):
            self.send_response(200)
            self.send_header('Content-type','text/html')
            self.end_headers()
            self.wfile.write('<html><head></head><body>'.encode())
            self.wfile.write('<img src="http://127.0.0.1:8080/cam.mjpg"/>'.encode())
            self.wfile.write('</body></html>'.encode())
            return


class ThreadedHTTPServer(ThreadingMixIn, HTTPServer):
    """Handle requests in a separate thread."""

def main():
    try:
        server = ThreadedHTTPServer(('0.0.0.0', 8080), CamHandler)
        print( "server started")
        server.serve_forever()
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        server.socket.close()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

I believe the data I'm sending could be sent as a numpy array, not too sure, please suggest.

Comment: How could you ensure that 66512 bytes could compose an image? And why do you need to pickle it? Why couldn't you just write raw data into disk as bytes?

Comment: I'm using jpeg compression over 320*240 image size, the image is always around 20KB. I could use direct raw file write, but what is it that is wrong in above code?

Comment: Found out that I was using incorrect usage of imdecode(..) Sorry for that guys!